# Pickling and unpickling dynamically loaded modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, python-module, python-importlib

I'm creating an object in the following way (*I know it's horrible, don't ask why, it's necessary*):

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.py') as temp:
    temp.write(code.encode('utf-8'))
    import importlib.util
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('a_temp_module', temp.name)
    temp_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(temp_module)
    special_snowflake_object = temp_module.SpecialSnowflake()
```

Now the class `SpecialSnowflake` implements two methods for saving and loading which essentially just pickle and unpickle it:

```
def save(self, file_path: str):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as fp:
        pickle.dump(self, fp)

@staticmethod
def load(file_path: str):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
        return pickle.load(fp)
```

But, upon calling `save` I get the error:

`_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'a_temp_module.SpecialSnowflake'>: import of module 'a_temp_module' failed`

This is rather strange, since I didn't know you could carry around an object instantiated from a call without carrying around the class definition itself, but apparently, this is what's happening here.

I assume that loading and saving could be done via:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.py') as temp:
    temp.write(code.encode('utf-8'))
    import importlib.util
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('a_temp_module', temp.name)
    temp_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(temp_module)
    special_snowflake_object_1.save(path_to_pickle)
    special_snowflake_object_2 = temp_module.SpecialSnowflake.load(path_to_pickle)
```

But I'd prefer for `save` to be callable without having to reload the module, I guess for load there's no alternative. My current thinking is I might be able to do this by hiding the loading of the module inside the `save` function and carrying around the code as a property of the object... but I'd hope there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: `pickle` doesn't "carry around the class definition". It remembers the name of the module defining the class, so that must be available. There's a third-party module named `dill` that *can* pickle class definitions I believe, so that may help.

Comment: A solution based on this doesn't seem to work in my case, since I don't have *just* a class definition I can exec, I have a class definition + some imports, i.e. a module

Comment: @George would you care to elaborate if my answer is satisfactory to you or is there something missing in it?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the `pickle` module [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#relationship-to-other-python-modules):

> pickle can save and restore class instances transparently, however the class definition must be importable and live in the same module as when the object was stored.

`pickle` can not pickle an instance of `a_temp_module.SpecialSnowflake`, because the module object stored in the `a_temp_module` variable had not actually been imported in the global context with the `import` statement.

As @martineau had stated in the comments, the `pickle` module does actually not store class definitions within a pickle file. The class definition must be importable from the same module.

Again quoting from the `pickle` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled):

> The following types can be pickled:
>
> **...**
>
> - *classes that are defined at the ***top level*** of a module*

The definition of the `SpecialSnowflake` class is also not defined at the top level of your `__main__` environment ( or whatever other environment where the code from the examples is ), therefore you can not pickle and unpickle `SpecialSnowflake` instances in that environment.